# Mudar o projeto do .NET 4.5 para o 4.5.2, como fazer?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio, instalador

Eu instalei o .NET 4.5.2 na maquina, reiniciei o Windows 7 e, depois de abrir o projeto, fui em `Debug > Projeto.Properties > Application` e tentei mudar a versão pelo combo `Target Framework`, porém lá não aparece a versão 4.5.2.

Já olhei o Regedit e o .Net está atualizado lá, também tentei reinstalá-lo e pede para reparar, o que indica a instalação dessa versão.

Meu Visual Studio é o 2013 com update 3, o sistema operacional é Windows 7 Ultimate.

Além de instalar, preciso fazer algo para conseguir mudar a versão do .NET do projeto?

Comment: Estava pensando aqui talvez você tenha outro problema. Você instalaou o http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42637? Sem ele você não terá determinadas funcionalidades no VS. Me fala isto p/ dar uma complementada na resposta.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 6):

Se você já instalou o [Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 Developer Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42637?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) está tudo correto e não precisa fazer mais nada.

Você desenvolve para a versão 4.5. A versão 4.5.2 é apenas uma atualização *in-place* completamente compatível com a 4.5. Ou seja se você desenvolver para a 4.5, ela vai rodar bem na 4.5, 4.5.1 ou 4.5.2 e ainda na 4.5.3 se vier a ter. Sua aplicação vai usar a versão mais atual que estiver instalada na máquina do usuário. Quando você define que está usando a versão 4.5 na sua aplicação, apenas está dizendo que não pode usar uma versão anterior ou incompatível (uma futura versão 5, por exemplo, **poderia** ser incompatível com a 4.5). Você não tem que se preocupar com micro-versões. Ainda bem.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).